# Take function doesn't work and cannot be sent to RavenDB for query

Tags: indexing, ravendb

Query Code:

```
var query = session.IndexQuery<App_OrgSearch.IndexResult, App_OrgSearch>();
var organizationUnitResults = query.Statistics(out stats)
                    .Skip(0)
                    .Take(5)
                    .AsProjection<Org>().ToList();

public static IRavenQueryable<TResult> IndexQuery<TResult, TIndex>(this IDocumentSession session)
            where TIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask, new()
        {
            return session.Query<TResult, TIndex>();
        }
```

App_OrgSearch is the index I defined as below:

```
public class App_OrgSearch : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Org, App_OrgSearch.IndexResult>
    {
        public class IndexResult
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string BusinessName { get; set; }
            public string ShortName { get; set; }
            public IList<string> Names { get; set; }
            public List<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
            public List<OrganizationUnitPhone> OrganizationUnitPhones { get; set; }
        }

        public App_OrganizationUnitSearch()
        {
            Map = docs => from doc in docs
                select new
                {
                    Id = doc.Id,
                    Names = new List<string>
                    {
                        doc.BusinessName,
                        doc.ShortName,
                    },
                    BusinessName = doc.BusinessName,
                    ShortName = doc.ShortName,
                    PhoneNumbers = doc.OrganizationUnitPhones.Where(x => x != null && x.Phone != null).Select(x => x.Phone.Number),

                };

            Indexes.Add(x => x.Names, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        }
    }
```

I have 27 records in database. I want to take 5, but after query, all 27 records are returned. Why does `Take` function not work?

Comment: Edited for clarity; removed ambiguous tag

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code seems wrong.

```
var query = session.IndexQuery<App_OrgSearch.IndexResult, App_OrgSearch>();
var organizationUnitResults = organizationUnitsQuery.Statistics(out stats)
```

What is `organizationUnitsQuery` ? You have the query as `query`, but there is no `IndexQuery` method on the session

Comment: I resolved this issue by change the function call order:
var organizationUnitResults = query.Statistics(out stats)
                    .AsProjection<Org>()
                    .Skip(0)
                    .Take(5)
                    .ToList();